# why always having indetermined limit?

Tags: limits

I have the following limit ;

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{z'(x)}{w'(x)}$$

I define $z(x)$ and $w(x)$ are similar. I define them as follows ;

$$z(x)=\frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}$$

$$w(x)=\frac{x^{1-b}}{1-b}$$

Normally, as the this limit gives us a indeterminate form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. I try to find it by applying Hôpital's rule. It yields

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{z''(x)}{w''(x)}$$

but this one gives always an indeterminate form (and will give always when differenciate it with respect to $x$).

What can I do to find the limit of this one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your limit.

Using your definitions for the fuctions

$$
\frac{z'(x)}{w'(x)}=x^{b-a}
$$

If $x \rightarrow 0$ then this limit exists if $b>a$ and is equal to $0$. If $b = a$ the limit is $1$. If $b < a$ the limit is $+\infty$ if $x$ is positive.